# Why could the filtered elements from a Java stream return an empty list after a String was converted to List?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I accessed a web table with selenium and collected all the table rows into a list:

```
List<WebElement> nameColumn = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[2]/span"));
```

I looped through the list, `getText` from the elements and stored the result in a `String`:

```
   for (WebElement tdElement : nameColumn) {
        String records = tdElement.getText();
    
    //To be able to filter the result so as to collect words starting with a particular pattern, I converted the `String` to a `List`:
    
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(records.split(",")));
        System.out.println(myList);
}
```

Output:

```
["test1"]
["testme"]
["demoit"]
["sampleit"]
["johndoe"]
["testeurope"]
["testusa"]
["testitaly"]
["gomali"]
```

`Using stream()`, I tried collecting elements that start with `test`:

```
List<String> filteredFields = myList.stream().filter(field -> field.startsWith("test")).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(filteredFields);
```

Output:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

An empty list was returned. Why could the filter be empty? Could it be because of the conversion of a `String` to a `List`? How do I achieve collecting all the elements that `startsWith` `test`?

The whole code bock looks like this:

```
public void demo() throws InterruptedException {
    List<WebElement> nameColumn = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[2]/span"));

    for (WebElement tdElement : nameColumn) {
      String records = tdElement.getText();

      //convert to List
      List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(records.split(",")));
      System.out.println(myList);

      //Get elements that start with test
      List<String> filteredFields = myList.stream().filter(field -> field.startsWith("test")).collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(filteredFields);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where exactly did you put that code involving `filteredFields`?

Comment: @ Louis Wasserman, `filteredFields` is holding `myList`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Please show your complete loop, starting with `for (WebElement tdElement : nameColumn)`, including the `filteredFields` code.

Comment: I don't know what more you are looking for. Thats all the relevant code, except you are looking for method and class names

Comment: I want to see one single block of code that has both `filteredFields` and your for loop, not two code blocks.  Yes, you've probably shown us "all the relevant code," but you haven't shown us how you fitted the two code blocks together, and that is relevant and important information.

Comment: The function block is provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arraylist contains words with quotes, i.e **"** *test1* **"**.

That is why you should not check directly with `field.startswith`. But you should first remove quote and then check `field.startswith`. 
Please use below :

```
List<String> filteredFields = myList.stream().filter(field -> field.substring(1, field.length()-1).startsWith("test")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Almost correct. Each row contains the output of a single list generated in the WebElement-loop. The outer brackets on each row are produced by ArrayList.toString() method and are not part of the data. The quotes however are part of each String. So your answer is correct if you change the offsets from 2 to 1. Or preferably just use field.startsWith("test", 1).

Comment: @abhinav3414, Beautiful. This works. Thanks

Comment: Also, if I want to strip off the double quotes surrounding the elements, can that be achieved?